# Classic asp: how to save a dictionary object in a cookie?

Tags: cookies, dictionary, asp-classic

This gives me the message "Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Server.CreateObject(...).cookies'" :

```
set response.cookies("x")= Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

and this also :

```
set mydictionary = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
mydictionary("1").add "0","allo"
set response.cookies("x")= mydictionary
```

How can I put a dictionary in a cookie? Thanks for help.

Comment: You don't: A dictionary is an Object but a cookie value ultimately needs to be a string - there is no automagic conversion between the two.

Comment: If you wanted to store the keys and values you would loop the dictionary and build a delimited string representation if the content (or add a cookie for each key). Bear in mind the cookies collection is already dictionary like.

Comment: `mydictionary("1").add ..` is also not valid : `mydictionary.add ..` is the correct form.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in comments you can not store dictionary in cookies because it is an object however you can use Session to store dictionary and use it for the current user session anyway you needed to.